# Web service client given WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

I am trying to create a web service client in Java. I am not aware of how to do it. This is a URL for WSDL: https://testservices.gatewayedi.com/PayerList/payerlist.asmx?wsdl

This is the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/">
      <s:element name="Ping">
        <s:complexType />
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="PingResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PingResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="AuthSOAPHeader" type="tns:AuthSOAPHeader" />
      <s:complexType name="AuthSOAPHeader">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="GetXMLPayerList">
        <s:complexType />
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetXMLPayerListResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetXMLPayerListResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="getDocLinks">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="pid" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="getDocLinksResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getDocLinksResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="PingSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Ping" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PingSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PingResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PingAuthSOAPHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthSOAPHeader" element="tns:AuthSOAPHeader" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetXMLPayerListSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetXMLPayerList" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetXMLPayerListSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetXMLPayerListResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetXMLPayerListAuthSOAPHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthSOAPHeader" element="tns:AuthSOAPHeader" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getDocLinksSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getDocLinks" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getDocLinksSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getDocLinksResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getDocLinksAuthSOAPHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthSOAPHeader" element="tns:AuthSOAPHeader" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="PayerListSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="Ping">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:PingSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:PingSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetXMLPayerList">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetXMLPayerListSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetXMLPayerListSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDocLinks">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getDocLinksSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getDocLinksSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="PayerListSoap" type="tns:PayerListSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Ping">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/Ping" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:PingAuthSOAPHeader" part="AuthSOAPHeader" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetXMLPayerList">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/GetXMLPayerList" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:GetXMLPayerListAuthSOAPHeader" part="AuthSOAPHeader" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDocLinks">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/getDocLinks" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:getDocLinksAuthSOAPHeader" part="AuthSOAPHeader" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="PayerListSoap12" type="tns:PayerListSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Ping">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/Ping" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
        <soap12:header message="tns:PingAuthSOAPHeader" part="AuthSOAPHeader" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetXMLPayerList">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/GetXMLPayerList" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
        <soap12:header message="tns:GetXMLPayerListAuthSOAPHeader" part="AuthSOAPHeader" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDocLinks">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/getDocLinks" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
        <soap12:header message="tns:getDocLinksAuthSOAPHeader" part="AuthSOAPHeader" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="PayerList">
    <wsdl:port name="PayerListSoap" binding="tns:PayerListSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://testservices.gatewayedi.com/PayerList/payerlist.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="PayerListSoap12" binding="tns:PayerListSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://testservices.gatewayedi.com/PayerList/payerlist.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

There are three methods in the service.

I am trying to call this method using SOAP.

The XML message format is:

```
POST /PayerList/payerlist.asmx HTTP/1.1 
Host: testservices.gatewayedi.com 
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: <<insert message length here>> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> <soap12:Header> <AuthSOAPHeader xmlns="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/"> <User><<insert user id here>>
</User> 
<Password><<insert user web password here>> </Password> 
</AuthSOAPHeader> 
</soap12:Header> <soap12:Body> <Ping xmlns="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/" />
 </soap12:Body> 
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Anyone who knows the solution please let me know.
Any help is really appreciable.

Answer (score 55):

As hinted in a comment to [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172118/web-service-client-in-java/4172152#4172152), my recommendation would be to use a JAX-WS implementation like JAX-WS RI (which is included in Java 6) or Apache CXF.

I'll use JAX-WS RI to illustrate my answer as it's available out of the box, on the command line (to explain the steps) but I'd recommend using an IDE with good JAX-WS support e.g. NetBeans (see the resources at the end of the answer).

#### 1. Generate JAX-WS artifacts from the WSDL

First run [`wsimport`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) to generate JAX-WS artifacts (to put it simply, the classes you'll need to invoke the web service):

```
wsimport -d generated -extension -keep -p com.gatewayedi.ws -XadditionalHeaders https://testservices.gatewayedi.com/PayerList/payerlist.asmx?wsdl
```

About the options:

- `-d` is used to specify the target directory for the generated stuff
- `-extension` is used to allow extensions (the WSDL is using a non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding)
- `-keep` is to keep generated `.java` sources (this is will ease the development)
- `-p` is used to specify a package for the generated artifacts
- `-XadditionalHeaders` is used to [map additional WSDL headers (that are not part of the input or output contract defined in the `portType` operation) to method parameters](http://jax-ws.java.net/guide/SOAP_headers.html#Mapping_additional_WSDL_headers_to_method_parameters) (this will make invoking the service easier).

Sorry if some of the vocabulary is cryptic but, well, welcome to SOAP web services :)

#### 2. Implement a client

Here is a simple client showing how to invoke one of the available operations using the generated classes:

```
import com.gatewayedi.ws.AuthSOAPHeader;
import com.gatewayedi.ws.PayerList;
import com.gatewayedi.ws.PayerListSoap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().callWebService();
    }

    private void callWebService() {
        PayerList service = new PayerList();
        PayerListSoap port = service.getPayerListSoap();

        AuthSOAPHeader authSOAPHeader = new AuthSOAPHeader();
        authSOAPHeader.setUser("test");
        authSOAPHeader.setPassword("test");

        String payerList = port.ping(authSOAPHeader);

        System.out.println(payerList);
    }

}
```

Below, the generated request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  standalone="no"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header>
<AuthSOAPHeader xmlns="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/">
<User>test</User>
<Password>test</Password>
</AuthSOAPHeader>
</S:Header>
<S:Body>
<Ping xmlns="https://ws.gatewayedi.com/"/>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Don't know what credentials you're supposed to pass though.

#### Resources

- [Developing JAX-WS Web Service Clients](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html) (start here)
- [Introducing JAX-WS 2.0 With the Java SE 6 Platform, Part 1](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/)
- [Creating a Simple Web Service and Client with JAX-WS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)
- [Creating a SOAP client with either Apache CXF or GlassFish Metro](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/soap_client_tutorial) (Glen Mazza's blog is a great resources)

#### Related questions

- [Java Webservice Client (Best way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588616/java-webservice-client-best-way)
- [What is the best java webservice framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062347/what-is-the-best-java-webservice-framework)

Comment: agreed (+1). axis is terribly buggy (even more so than CXF :-))

Comment: @seanizer: This answer summarizes pretty well all the love I have for Axis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588616/java-webservice-client-best-way. Never again.

Comment: I couldnt find XadditionalHeaders option in the wsimport. Is there an any alternative.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: As Pascal appears to have recent experience on this, it's probably worth reading his comment:

> Nowadays, I wouldn't use Axis (I actually recommend against using it). Apache CXF or JAX-WS RI (which is included in Java 6 and offers wsimport and wsgen command line commands) are IMO much better stacks and easier to use.

So, look at the [Apache CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/) and the [introduction to JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/).

---

**Original answer**

Have you tried using [Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/)? It's a while since I've done any Java web services, but that was what I used last time... You'll want to look at [WSDL2Java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) to generate code from the WSDL.

Comment: Nowadays, I wouldn't use Axis (I actually recommend against using it). Apache CXF or JAX-WS RI (which is included in Java 6 and offers wsimport and wsgen command line commands) are IMO much better stacks and easier to use.

Comment: @user506518: So did you try following the links and reading up on it? You can't expect us to do *all* the work for you.

Comment: I concur with not using Axis it is very old and .net refuses to play nice with it. Especially if the Axis multiref global configuration is set to on.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what has been suggested above, you can also use an IDE such as [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/). It basically allows you to create a webservice client through wizards, without having to go through making all the configurations yourself. [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OytDHyD-f4o) video shows you how to first create a webservice and then how to create its corresponding client. Note that in the video, whoever is doing the tutorial consumes the webservice through another web application. If you want to consume the webservice through a desktop application, just do the same procedure, the only difference is that instead of a webproject, you do it on the project you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment to have a look at Apache Axis2 or Apache WSIF (Web Services Invocation Framework).

Links:

- http://ws.apache.org/axis2/
- http://ws.apache.org/wsif/