# Writing a SOAP Client in Java

Tags: java, soap-client

I have written a custom SOAP client in Java and though it works, I feel the way I wrote it is very elementary. I'm not good in OOP and as you can see, all the work is done in a single class. Can you please help to improve this or give any idea.

I have read articles about creating soap clients such as [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/) and I can say that the classes are very well organized.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class ConInfoService {
private final static String BLANK = "";
    private final static String SOAP_SERVER = "http://server.com/ConInfoService.asmx";
    private final static String PREFIX_XSI = "xsi"; 
    private final static String PREFIX_XSD = "xsd"; 
    private final static String PREFIX_SOAP = "soap";
    private final static String URI_HOST = "server.com";
    private final static String URI_GETCULIST = "http://tempuri.org/GetCuList";
    private final static String URI_XSI = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance";
    private final static String URI_XSD = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema";
    private final static String URI_SOAP = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    private final static String URI_TEMPURI = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final static String HEADER_HOST = "Host";
    private final static String HEADER_SOAPACTION = "SOAPAction";

    public SOAPMessage getCuList(Date asDate,  String asConAvailable, String asConChanged, String asMso) throws Exception {
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            String soapServer = SOAP_SERVER;;
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = createSOAPRequest(asDate, asConAvailable, asConChanged, asMso);
            return soapConnection.call(soapMessage, soapServer);
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(Date asDate,  String asConAvailable, String asConChanged, String asMso) throws Exception {
        if (asDate != null && asConAvailable != null && asConChanged != null && asMso != null) {
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(PREFIX_XSI, URI_XSI);
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(PREFIX_XSD, URI_XSD);
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(PREFIX_SOAP, URI_SOAP);

            SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
            SOAPElement getCuListElem = soapBody.addChildElement("GetCuList", BLANK, URI_TEMPURI);
            SOAPElement asDateElem = getCuListElem.addChildElement("asDate", BLANK);
            SOAPElement asConAvailableElem = getCuListElem.addChildElement("asConAvailable", BLANK);
            SOAPElement asConChangedElem = getCuListElem.addChildElement("asConChanged", BLANK);
            SOAPElement asMsoElem = getCuListElem.addChildElement("asMso", BLANK);      

            asDateElem.addTextNode(formatDate(asDate));
            asConAvailableElem.addTextNode(asConAvailable.trim());
            asConChangedElem.addTextNode(asConChanged.trim());
            asMsoElem.addTextNode(asMso.trim());

            MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
            headers.addHeader(HEADER_HOST, URI_HOST);
            headers.addHeader(HEADER_SOAPACTION, URI_GETCULIST);

            soapMessage.saveChanges();

            return soapMessage;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use JAX-WS/JAXB in a way for wsdl-based class generation? Such as [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_glassfish6.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173073/1051509)?

Comment: I second the use a JAX-WS implementation (or the one built into the JDK itself). If not for easy of use, JAX-WS and JAXB are just so wonderfully documented!