# Soap web service client

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl, integration-testing

We are integrating our software with another company using a webservice. They created a `SOAP` web service which we now need to test.

I'm trying to write a java program with Eclipse IDE. When creating a web service client, I enter the wsdl:

```
[https://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/index.php/gt/property/soap?wsdl]*
```

but I keep getting a message that states: `The service definition is invalid`.

Any ideas as to why this would be or any links I could check out would be appreciated. I have searched but haven't found anything that helped me yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for a Java program you could use,

[Web service client given WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172118/web-service-client-given-wsdl)

But if you just want to test the web service, you could always use program like SoapUI