# Insert headers in WSDL using wsimport

Tags: soap, wsdl, wsimport

Can I insert headers in WSDL while using wsimport ?
I did found out that "wsimport -XadditionalHeaders sample.wsdl" could be used but I could not figure out how to declare it in my pom.xml file.
Any lead would prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below link for adding additional headers in wsimport.

[Web service client given WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172118/web-service-client-given-wsdl/4172152#4172152)