# Generate Java web service client from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, siebel

Is it possible to generate java web-service client using a WSDL file(from local file-system)?

I am working with siebel and Java. siebel developer send me a WSDL file, I need to generate java web-service client. How can I generate client using that WSDL file which is saved on my desktop like a normal file?

I know how to generate web-services clients in Java using eclipse, But eclipse is looking for a WSDL url. which siebel can not provide.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web service client given WSDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172118/web-service-client-given-wsdl)

Comment: In Eclipse, right click your project and create a new web client. It will ask you for your wsdl (which you should have on your project path) and stage of deployment. There are some additional options which aren't necessarily important. Then the client gets generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in eclipse just copy the wsdl file into the project root and then when you click to generate instead of url click browse choose the project and select your wsdl.

[image]

Right click on project->new->other

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]