# Collision error while generating JAX-WS artifacts from the WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a web service client in Java. i am following the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172118/web-service-client-given-wsdl) , but i am facing the following errors. and i don't know how to fix them . I tried netBeans but same errors

```
 [ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 1 of http://41.137.246.222/Service.svc?xsd=xsd3

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 1 of http://41.137.246.222/Service.svc?xsd=xsd3

Exception in thread "main"         com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.AbortException
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2283)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:183)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:429)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:190)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:159)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)
```

here is the link of the [WSDL](http://41.137.246.222/Service.svc?wsdl)

and this is the first line in xsd3

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SABil.DataObjects" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SABil.DataObjects">
<xs:import schemaLocation="http://41.137.246.222/Service.svc?xsd=xsd4" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"/>
```

Any help is really appreciable.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with importing xsd4 inside xsd3 AND inside wsdl?