# How to implement web services in java

Tags: java, web-services

I'm actually working on a website project. I'm new with web services. I have 4 years experience in object oriented programming (java, c#, ...). I have read a lot on web services but none of my documentations are telling how to use all the technologies to make a real web service project.

What I want to do is:
1. Use a MySQL backend mapped with JPA in Java;
2. Use web services to present some functionalities with ... (JBoss, ... there is to much possibilities, I do not know which I should choose)
3. Create a dynamic web project (maybe in Jsp to keep the Java perspective) to present web service data to the end-user with HTML, Javascript, jQuery, ...

If you can help me with documentations, links or real project implementation samples, it will be greatly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Anything except Axis 2. I would personally go for Apache CXF or JAX-WS RI. Check these previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442582/java-web-service-framework-library-which-is-a-better-one-and-why, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588616/java-webservice-client-best-way/3590252, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062347/what-is-the-best-java-webservice-framework,

Comment: @Pascal: what's wrong with Axis2? I was planning on getting started with Java Web Services with Axis2...

Comment: @ssahmed555 I gave some reasons in the second link of my comment. Just google a bit or browse SO for more opinions (see for example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289977/recommended-framework-for-java-web-services). To sum up, you'll never see me recommending Axis 2 and *I* will never use it again (unless forced but this shouldn't happen), there are much better, cleaner, *easier to use*, etc WS stacks. But some people like pain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this](http://www.roseindia.net/webservices/buildingsimplewebservice.shtml). for beginner

I would suggest go for [**Spring Web Services**](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html) from your env. It would be better

Comment: The question was more around which technologies to use creating webservices in Java. I already know how to create/manage webservices in Java... do you have any clues ? JBoss with CXF, Axis, ...?

Comment: @dutertimes: Java has two standards for web services: JAX-WS for SOAP web services and JAX-RS for REST web services.  Each of these have several implementations... Spring Web Services and Apache CXF support both standards.

Comment: @R.Bemrose Spring WS doesn't implement neither JAX-WS nor JAX-RS. Spring WS is a very minimalistic WS stack.

Comment: @Pascal: So... should I use Spring WS for my described project or is it too "Simple" for it? I don't know anything about Spring

Comment: @dutertimes It might do the job but I'm not fan personally and, as I wrote in my initial comment to your question, *I would personally go for Apache CXF or JAX-WS RI*.

Answer (score 0):

I have found something interesting using spring web services with eclipse that I will use with my project at this link: 
[Sprint Web service tutorial with Eclipse](http://www.lulu.com/content/content_download_redirect.php?metaId=1090073)

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, here's a NetBeans tutorial: [Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html)