# How to write web services with Java

Tags: java, web-services, http, web

I usually write my web services using PHP + Mysql, in a simplified way: reading the POST/GET params, connecting to the MySQL database and finally printing a JSON.

I'd like to check how to do this with a Java server, I've never programmed Java web servers and I'd like to know what should I study to learn to do it

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement web services in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736926/how-to-implement-web-services-in-java)

Comment: That does not even mention different web services architectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing here that you have a good understand of java programming.

Fisrtly, I think you should understand java for web.
I recommend this book:

**Head First Servlets and JSP**
[http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-Certified/dp/0596516681/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516681)

Then you can learn web services with java:

**Java Web Services: Up and Running**
[http://www.amazon.com/Java-Web-Services-Up-Running/dp/1449365116](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449365116)

Of course, there are many tutorials over the internet as well, but books give you a lot of background information.

Answer (score 2):

I wanna suggest you garner understanding of the two main WebServices Architectures then decide which ones suit your case/use best

REST (GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH) JAX-RS

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

vs SOAP bases JAX-WS

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html

Comparing them:
[Main differences between SOAP and RESTful web services in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131965/main-differences-between-soap-and-restful-web-services-in-java)